# 'str' object has no attribute 'n '

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, attributes

I am getting an error in python:

File "C:\Users\user\workspace\LINKAGE\2.py", line 13, in **init**
self.n = points[0].n 
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'n'

What does this error mean and what did I do wrong to cause it?

The python code is:

```
import math,sys

class Cluster:

    points = []
    elem = int(raw_input("how many points do you want to cluster?"))
    for i in range(0, elem):
        points.append(raw_input("Enter next point :"))
        print points

    def __init__(self, points):
        self.points= points
        self.n = points[0].n 

        for p in points:
            if p.n != self.n: raise Exception("ILLEGAL: MULTISPACE CLUSTER")

    # Return a string representation of this Cluster
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.points)


    # Return the single-linkage distance between this and another Cluster
    def getSingleDistance(self, cluster):
        ret = getDistance(self.points[0], cluster.points[0])
        for p in self.points:
            for q in cluster.points:
                distance = getDistance(p, q)
                if distance < ret: ret = distance
        return ret
    # Return the complete-linkage distance between this and another Cluster
    def getCompleteDistance(self, cluster):
        ret = getDistance(self.points[0], cluster.points[0])
        for p in self.points:
            for q in cluster.points:
                distance = getDistance(p, q)
                if distance > ret: ret = distance
        return ret
    # Return the centroid-linkage distance between this and another Cluster

    def fuse(self, cluster):
        # Forbid fusion of Clusters in different spaces
        if self.n != cluster.n: raise Exception("ILLEGAL FUSION")
        points = self.points
        points.extend(cluster.points)
        return Cluster(points) 


# -- Return a distance matrix which captures distances between all Clusters
def makeDistanceMatrix(clusters, linkage):
    ret = dict()
    for i in range(len(clusters)):
        for j in range(len(clusters)):
            if j == i: break
            if linkage == 's':
                ret[(i,j)] = clusters[i].getSingleDistance(clusters[j])
            elif linkage == 'c':
                ret[(i,j)] = clusters[i].getCompleteDistance(clusters[j])
            else: raise Exception("INVALID LINKAGE")
    return ret
# -- Return Clusters of Points formed by agglomerative clustering

def agglo(points, linkage, cutoff):
    # Currently, we only allow single, complete, or average linkage
    if not linkage in [ 's', 'c' ]: raise Exception("INVALID LINKAGE")
    # Create singleton Clusters, one for each Point
    clusters = []
    for p in points: clusters.append(Cluster([p]))
    # Set the min_distance between Clusters to zero
    min_distance = 0
    # Loop until the break statement is made
    while (True):
        # Compute a distance matrix for all Clusters
        distances = makeDistanceMatrix(clusters, linkage)
        # Find the key for the Clusters which are closest together
        min_key = distances.keys()[0]
        min_distance = distances[min_key]
        for key in distances.keys():
            if distances[key] < min_distance:
                min_key = key
                min_distance = distances[key]
        # If the min_distance is bigger than the cutoff, terminate the loop
        # Otherwise, agglomerate the closest clusters
        if min_distance > cutoff or len(clusters) == 1: break
        else:
            c1, c2 = clusters[min_key[0]], clusters[min_key[1]]
            clusters.remove(c1)
            clusters.remove(c2)
            clusters.append(c1.fuse(c2))
    # Return the list of Clusters
    return clusters
# -- Get the Euclidean distance between two Points
def getDistance(a, b):
    # Forbid measurements between Points in different spaces
    if a.n != b.n: raise Exception("ILLEGAL: NON-COMPARABLE POINTS")
    # Euclidean distance between a and b is sqrt(sum((a[i]-b[i])^2) for all i)
    ret = 0.0
    for i in range(a.n):
        ret = ret+pow((a.coords[i]-b.coords[i]), 2)
    return math.sqrt(ret)
# -- Create a random Point in n-dimensional space

# -- Plot Clusters using Tkinter
def plot(clusters):
    root = Tk()
    cp = ClusterPlot(root)
    root.mainLoop()
# -- Main function
def main(args):
    linkage, agglo_cutoff = 's', 150.0
    points = Cluster.points
    # Create num_points random Points in n-dimensional space, print them
    print "\nPOINTS:"
    # Cluster the points using the agglomerative algorithm, print the results
    clusters = agglo( points, linkage, agglo_cutoff)
    print "\nAGGLOMERATIVE\nCLUSTERS:"
    for c in clusters: print "C:", c

if __name__ == "__main__": main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: I don't understand this line: self.n = points[0].n ?? can you explain what you are intending to do here

Comment: `points` appears to be a list of strings, hence `points[0].n` is an issue.

Comment: Methinks, do you have two different uses of the name `points`?  You might wish to change one of them.  Before the `__init__` you append a string (from `raw_input`) to `points`.   `points` is a list of strings.  BTW:  your question title is a little confusing, the error message says it is a `str`, not an `int`.

Comment: I cannot think of a single built-in Python type with an "n" attribute, so I'm wondering what you are trying to do by "self.n" unless you are passing your own type, object (namedtuple or similar), or class instance.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning about my title, I changed it. Ok so can i write  points = [int(i) for i in points] ? By changing you mean deleting one of them??

Comment: Are you trying to convert an input from the user to integers? If so, then yes, do somevar = [int(i) for i in points] #somevar could be points, to reassign back to points.

Comment: No, I don't mean deleting one of your `points`, I mean using a different name.  Although Python is dynamic and you can assign different types to the same name, use that feature with care.  Where you have your list of strings, maybe call that `str_points`.  Even if you had a list of integers an int does not have an attribute called `n`.

Comment: The more I look at your code the more I am convinced that you have tied yourself in knots by reusing the name `points`.   Decide what type `points` should refer to, then check every occurrence.  Where it is not that type use a different name.  For example:  `int_points = [int(i) for i in str_points] `.

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to the fact that `points` is a list. So when you use `points[0]`, it calls the first item inside the list, which should be a string. For example:

```
srtings = ['hello']
print strings[0]          #returns hello, which is a string
```

Now since `.n` in `points.n` means that `points` is a function, which can contain a variable named `n` and can be used if you call `points.n`. But it is not, it's a list. And since lists can never have any attributes, `points.n` will raise an error at all times as long `points` is not a function (the other time is when `n` is not defined in your function). As an example when `points.n` can be called without an error:

```
def points():
    n = []    #You could get an item out of the list by calling points.n[x]
```